# Error while fetching data from api in react "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, json, api, express

I'm using a React hook component to fetch data from an api writed in express.
It's only working while fetching all the data, trying to fetch any specific value, it crashes.

For example: It's fetching `users.users` correctly but not `users.users.details`

react hooks component:

```
const Api = () => {
   
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([{}]);
  var {username} = useParams();
  var objdetails = useRef();
  
  function FetchApi(nameuser){
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`/api/users/${nameuser}/details`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => setUsers({users}))
    }, [nameuser])
  } 
  
  FetchApi(username);
  objdetails.current = JSON.stringify(users.users);
  
  
  return(
  <Styledthing>
    <div>
      <h2>User information from Github Api</h2>
      <ul>
        {JSON.stringify(objdetails.current)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </Styledthing>
  );
    
}

export default Api;
```

api in express:

```
async pesquisarDetails (request,response){
    let {username} = request.params
    var details;

    await axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + username).then(function(resposta){
        details = resposta.data.login;
 
        return response.json({details});
    }).catch((err) => {
        response.json({ msg:"User not found" + err + username });
    })
}
```

Here's what happens in my browser(chrome) console:

> api.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'details')

Comment: the property details does not exist on the response you sent back

Comment: I don't get it, when I'm fetching `JSON.stringify(users.users)` it is printing `"{\"details\":\"someuser\"}"` how the property details does not exist?

Comment: Where is the property `details` on the **string** `"{\"details\":\"someuser\"}"`? A string has a `length` property, but it has no `details` property. Remove `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
objdetails.current = JSON.stringify(users.users.details);
```

try this:

```
objdetails.current = JSON.stringify(users.users?.details);
```

Comment: And how would that help get the `details` property?

Comment: `users.users?.details` same as `if (users.users) return users.users.details`, it will check `users.users` if defined then return the value of `details` properety
the problem with your code is in the first render of Api component the state `users` is equals to [{}] so `users.users` is undefind, if you try to access to `details ` property this will crush your code with `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`, but if you use this method `users.users?.details` it keeps waiting for the data until it comes from the server then read the property `details`

Comment: No, it won't "wait for the data"; it will simply return undefined instead of throwing the TypeError (the statement is outside of the `useEffect` and the `run` and thus only runs the one time). Also, the problem is the fact the OP is using `JSON.stringify` at all; there's no need for it. This code hides the logical error instead of fixing it.

Comment: Have you tried it ?